# How to insert space after a character if there is no space already using SED?

Tags: sed

Say there is a character like this `#ま`. If I wanted to add a space after this i could do `sed -i "s/#ま/#ま\ /g" *` to add a space. But I would like to not do that because it would create a problem where there are double spaces.

Given a text such as `#あの #ま高校生の頃に. #あの #ま 高校生の頃に`. How do I add a space after `#ま` if there is no space in the beginning?

so the output would be something like

```
#あの #ま 高校生の頃に. #あの #ま 高校生の頃に
```

Comment: Maybe `sed -i 's/#ま */#ま /g' *`?

Comment: @jared_mamrot the problem with that is that I have double spaces everywhere in my files. And I need them. So I cannot mess with that

Comment: Using the same logic, `sed 's/#ま/#ま\ /g; s/#ま\ \ /#ま\ /g' file` will add a space after every #ま, but if the #ま is then followed by two spaces, it will reduce it back to one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sed` with `-r` for regular expression.

For your example, you can use this command:

```
sed -i -r 's/#ま([^ ])/#ま \1/g' <file>
```

Essentially, you are searching for `#ま[^ ]`, which is a `#ま` followed by exactly **one** non-space character. Then, you are replacing all such matches with `#ま<space><that non-space character>`.